# Solving runtime of T(n) = n^(1/2)T(n^(1/2)) + n

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

I am trying to find the recurrence runtime of the following:

```
T(n) = n^(1/2)T(n^(1/2)) + n
```

But I am unable to find the sum or even an equation that would relate g(n) to the summation of the recurrence. Could someone assist me with the summation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [cs.se] or [math.se].

Comment: its about computer science. Not off topic whatsoever

Comment: @user3320687 did you see the link to http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ? you might have better luck there.

Answer (score 1):

These type of recursions can be solved by unrolling the recursion, spotting the similarities between elements.

[image]

Now at some point the recursion will exhaust itself. This will happen if `T(...) = T(a) = b`. Any reasonable `a` will work, so I selected 2. Solving the equation `n^(1/2^k) = 2` by taking `log` of both sides, you get: `k = log(log(n))`. Now substitute it back in your recursion:

[image]

Limit of `2^(-loglogn)` is equal to `0` if `n -> infinity`, so the first element in summation is equal to b. The complexity is `O(n * log log (n))`

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n)=n^(1/2) T(n^(1/2)+n

    =n^(1/2)[ n^(1/2^2)T(n^(1/2^2)+n^(1/2)]+n

    =n^(3/2^2)T(n^(1/2^2)+2n

    =n^(3/2^2)[n^1/2^3 T(n^(1/2^3)+n^(1/2^3)]+2n

    = and so on 

    assume n^(1/2^k)=2
           1/2^k logn=1
           logn=2k
           log logn = k

   = n^(1-1/2^k)T(n^(1/2^k)+kn
   = n/n(1/2^k)T(2)+kn
   = n/2*2+nloglogn
   =n+nloglogn
   = O(nloglogn)
```